# Ansible merge dictionaries using with_items and vars stores only last item

Tags: ansible

Trying to create a dictionary per item and merge them

```
---
- name: TestingLab
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Hello Vars
      set_fact:
        two_nums:
          - 1
          - 2

    - name: create empty dict
      set_fact:
        ids: {}

    - name: Merge all
      vars:
        single_entry: "{ '{{ item }}': {{ item }} }"
      set_fact:
        ids: "{{ ids | combine(single_entry) }}"
      with_items: "{{ two_nums }}"

    - name: Print Result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ids }}"
```

I thought I followed the right guidelines but I seem to be getting only the last item afterwards:

> ok: [localhost] => {
> "msg": {
> "2": 2
> } }

I tried replacing the `single_entry` with the expression in `vars` but it does not run.
Is there a different syntax to get this done?

EDIT: version info

```
ansible-playbook 2.5.1
python version = 2.7.17 [GCC 7.5.0]
```

Comment: Python 2.7 went end-of-life back in Janurary 2020, and Ansible 2.5.1 was released over three years ago. Ansible 2.5 doesn't handle structured variables as well as modern Ansible versions. Your best option is to upgrade.

Comment: it's part of a vm cluster that have frozen versions (for the near future at least), I got to work with these versions for now..

Comment: Alright it's a bug in v2.5.1: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ansible/+bug/1780278

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the filters *dict* and [*zip*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest). The *zip* is available since 2.3, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        d2: "{{ dict(two_nums|zip(two_nums)) }}"
    - debug:
        var: d2
    - debug:
        var: d2|type_debug
```

gives

```yaml
  d2:
    1: 1
    2: 2

  d2|type_debug: dict
```

If this does not work try Jinja and the filter [*from_yaml*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json), e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    two_nums:
      - 1
      - 2
    l1: |-
      {% for i in two_nums %}
      {{ i }}: {{ i }}
      {% endfor %}
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        d1: "{{ l1|from_yaml }}"
    - debug:
        var: d1
    - debug:
        var: d1|type_debug
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  d1:
    1: 1
    2: 2

  d1|type_debug: dict
```

---

If you need the keys to be strings quote it, e.g.

```yaml
    l1: |-
      {% for i in two_nums %}
      "{{ i }}": {{ i }}
      {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  d1:
    '1': 1
    '2': 2
```

In the first case, *map* the list's items to [*string*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.string), e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        d2: "{{ dict(two_nums|map('string')|zip(two_nums)) }}"
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  d2:
    '1': 1
    '2': 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the behavior you're describing. Running your
playbook verbatim, I get as output:

```
TASK [Print Result] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "1": 1,
        "2": 2
    }
}
```

I'm using Ansible core 2.11.2, but I've also tested your playbook with Ansible 2.9.20 and I get the same output.

I would probably drop the `set_fact` task, and also change how you're
setting `single_entry`:

```
- name: TestingLab
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Hello Vars
      set_fact:
        two_nums:
          - 1
          - 2

    - name: Merge all
      vars:
        ids: {}
        single_entry: "{{ {item: item} }}"
      set_fact:
        ids: "{{ ids | combine(single_entry) }}"
      with_items: "{{ two_nums }}"

    - name: Print Result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ids }}"
```

In this version, the template expression is returning a dictionary,
and only requires a single set of Jinja template markers. I'm curious
if this version behaves any differently for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get only the last item. Editing above to add version to the post